# Multi Factor Authentication Phone Factor Discontinued?

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication

We received an email from Microsoft a couple weeks ago that states "discontinuing Multi-Factor Authentication SDK", does this include phone factor? If so, what would be a few alternatives?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/183b76dd-3af2-4c36-a0e1-506fdcd0c14f/azure-mfa-sdk?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: Hi there, looks like you already got an answer in the comment above. For future reference, StackOverflow is for coding questions, these types of questions should be posted in a sister site, perhaps https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-authprovider#caveats-related-to-the-azure-mfa-sdk) Microsoft had discontinued support for the SDK since November 14, 2018. After that time, calls to the SDK will fail.

You need to configure a [conditional access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa) for your application that will prompt users to do MFA. For more information please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-getstarted#enable-multi-factor-authentication-with-conditional-access)

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_bla3YhkmHevVouF&Q_CHL=gl
>